# ¿Por qué no puedo generar e imprimir una matriz al instanciarla desde una clase a la main en java?

Tags: java, poo, netbeans

Lo que quiero es poder generar, llenar e imprimir una matriz por medio de métodos de una clase a la clase main. Pero no me deja dice que estoy fuera de los límites. Ya lo probé hacer en otro proyecto y me deja sin ningún problema desde la clase main. Soy bastante nuevo en POO, no veo como arreglar este problema.

[image: Instanciando la clase donde se debería generar...]

[image: clase donde genero la matriz]

[image: Codigo de matriz funcionando en una clase main.]

Comment: Imprime `Matriz.length` para ver cuál es el tamaño de la matriz. Así te darás cuenta que la matriz no tiene el tamaño que crees que tiene. El tamaño corresponde a las "filas". Dramaturgo te explicó bien por qué sucede.

Answer (score 3):

Recuerda adjuntar tu código como texto y no como imagen,en POO debes tener presente que los objetos creados deben tener los atributos propios de la clase mediante el constructor, vos solo estas inicializando a `filas` y `columnas` mas no a `Matriz` el cual debes inicializar dentro del constructor y no fuera de el

```
private int filas,columnas;
private char[][] Matriz;

public Tablero(int filas,int columnas){

this.filas=filas;
this.columnas=columnas;
this.Matriz=new char[filas][columnas];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que estas excediendo en el numero de iteraciones, por lo que te indica este error, una solución rápida es disminuir en uno filas y columnas en tu bucles:

```
public void RellenarTablero(){
    for(int i = 0; i < filas - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnas - 1; j++){
            Matriz[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }
}

public void ImprimirTablero(){
    for(int i = 0; i < filas  -1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnas - 1; j++){
            System.out.print(Matriz[i][j]); 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(""); 
}
```